# Need help creating alert when line is broken in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am struggling to create an alert when  RSI value crossing over the highest line plotted based on last unbroken RSI HH value,

and similarly an alert when RSI crossing down the lowest line, plotted based on last unbroken RSI LL value,

to give you an idea, I tried this code, but it does't work

if rsi > linehh
alert(str.tostring(syminfo.ticker) + ' crossing above trendline', alert.freq_once_per_bar)

here is the main code the the script.

```
//@version=5
indicator("RSI Lines", overlay=false, max_bars_back = 500)

////INPUTs
inputgroup = "**********INPUTs**********"
shdiv = input.bool(defval = true, title = "Show Divergences", group=inputgroup)
shpoints = input.bool(defval = true, title = "Show Points", group=inputgroup)
shdate = input.bool(defval = true, title = "Show Dates", group=inputgroup)
shtline = input.bool(defval = true, title = "Show Trend Lines", group=inputgroup)
shbg = input.bool(defval = false, title = "Show StdDev Background", group=inputgroup)



////RSI
rsigroup = "**********RSI**********"
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title='RSI Length', group = rsigroup)
src = input(close, 'RSI Source', group = rsigroup)
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), len)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - 100 / (1 + up / down)
plot(rsi, 'RSI', color=color.new(#7E57C2, 0))

band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
bandm = hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")



////STDDEV
drawLine(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, ExtendType, Color, LineStyle) =>
    var line Line = na
    Line := line.new(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, xloc.bar_index, ExtendType, Color, LineStyle, 1)
    line.delete(Line[1])

rsdcr2(PeriodMinusOne, Deviations, Estimate) =>
    var period = PeriodMinusOne + 1
    var devDenominator = Estimate == 'Unbiased' ? PeriodMinusOne : period
    Ex = 0.0
    Ex2 = 0.0
    Exy = 0.0
    Ey = 0.0
    for i = 0 to PeriodMinusOne by 1
        closeI = nz(rsi[i])
        Ex := Ex + i
        Ex2 := Ex2 + i * i
        Exy := Exy + closeI * i
        Ey := Ey + closeI
        Ey
    ExEx = Ex * Ex
    slope = Ex2 == ExEx ? 0.0 : (period * Exy - Ex * Ey) / (period * Ex2 - ExEx)
    linearRegression = (Ey - slope * Ex) / period
    intercept = linearRegression + bar_index * slope
    deviation = 0.0
    for i = 0 to PeriodMinusOne by 1
        deviation := deviation + math.pow(nz(rsi[i]) - (intercept - bar_index[i] * slope), 2.0)
        deviation
    deviation := Deviations * math.sqrt(deviation / devDenominator)
    correlate = ta.correlation(rsi, bar_index, period)
    r2 = math.pow(correlate, 2.0)
    [linearRegression, slope, deviation, correlate, r2]
periodTrend = 140
deviationsAmnt = 1.1
estimatorType = 'Unbiased'
var extendType = 'Right'
periodMinusOne = periodTrend - 1
[linReg, slope, deviation, correlate, r2] = rsdcr2(periodMinusOne, deviationsAmnt, estimatorType)
endPointBar = bar_index - periodTrend + 1
endPointY = linReg + slope * periodMinusOne

////TRENDLINEs
trendgroup = "**********TREND LINE**********"
length = input(21, title='Zigzag Length')

r = rsi[length]
l = rsi[14]

ph = ta.pivothigh(rsi,length,length)
pl = ta.pivotlow(rsi,length,length)
valH = ta.valuewhen(ph,r,0)
valL = ta.valuewhen(pl,r,0)
valpH = ta.valuewhen(ph,r,1)
valpL = ta.valuewhen(pl,r,1)

d = math.abs(r)
n = bar_index
label lbl = na
HIH = valH > valpH ? "HH" : na 
HIL = valH < valpH ? "LH" : na
LOL = valL < valpL ? "LL" : na
LOH = valL > valpL ? "HL" : na

if ph and valH > valpH and shtline
    lbl := label.new(n[length],math.max(r,l),HIH,color=#ff1100  ,
      style=label.style_label_down,textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny)
    label.delete(lbl[1])
    linehh = line.new(n[length],math.max(r,l), bar_index, math.max(r,l), extend=extend.right, color=color.red)
    line.delete(linehh[1])

else if pl and valL < valpL and shtline
    lbl := label.new(n[length],math.min(r,l),LOL,color=#009c0c   ,  
      style=label.style_label_up,textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny)
    label.delete(lbl[1]) 
    linell = line.new(n[length],math.min(r,l), bar_index, math.min(r,l), extend=extend.right, color=color.green)
    line.delete(linell[1])
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`linehh` is of type line. You need a price value.

You can get the line's `y2` value and set an alert when the price crosses it.

```
price = line.get_y2(linehh)

if (rsi >= price)
    // Alert
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this but it didn't work